# How to use the mold linker with cargo?

Tags: rust, linker, rust-cargo, mold

I'm using lld as my linker currently for Rust, but recently encountered the mold project, which is faster than lld. I'd like to try it for Rust compilation, but I'm not sure how to pass it in as my linker. In my `.cargo/config` file I've got:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld",
]
```

But I can't just change that `lld` to `mold`, or provide the path to the `mold` executable. Is there a way to get gcc to accept a path to a linker?

Comment: [`-Clinker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#linker) “controls which linker `rustc` invokes to link your code.  It takes a path to the linker executable.”

Comment: @eggyal looks like you could make an answer

Comment: @mcarton: I don’t know anything about `mold`, and therefore other options may also need to be set (if indeed it’s compatible with rustc at all).

Comment: You usually change the linker with these lines in `.cargo/config: `[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "/usr/bin/mold"
`. But just like @eggyal, I don't know mold either to guess if it will work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Mold can now be used with Clang by simply adding this to `~/.cargo/config.toml`

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "/usr/bin/clang"
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=--ld-path=/usr/bin/mold"]
```

*Note: Mold may be installed at `/usr/local/bin/mold` if installed from source so the flags should be `rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=--ld-path=/usr/local/bin/mold"]`. Run `$ which mold` to double check where it's installed*

You can check it's worked by running `readelf -p .comment target/<type>/<binary_name>`

```sh
$ readelf -p .comment target/debug/my_binary

String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (GNU) 11.1.0
  [    13]  mold 1.0.0 (compatible with GNU ld and GNU gold)
```

Comment: Note, my installation of mold put the executable into `/usr/local/bin/mold`

Comment: @aName which distro are you using? I'll add some detail to the answer.

Comment: Following the instructions at https://github.com/rui314/mold#compile-mold gave me an executable at `/usr/local/bin/mold`.

Comment: The above did not work for me - I needed
`rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/mold"]`, as specified at https://github.com/rui314/mold#how-to-use

Comment: Ahh I see, it looks like the difference between installing from a package manager and installing from the makefile.

Comment: Setting `rustflags` does not affect native executables built while crosscompiling (for example, build scripts are built as executables for the build system while compiling for a different target).

Answer (score 17):

gcc does not accept an arbitrary path as an argument for `-fuse-ld`, unfortunately. Instead of tweaking `.cargo/config` file, try running `cargo build` as `path/to/mold -run cargo build`. By doing this, cargo runs under an influence of mold, and all invocations of `/usr/bin/ld`, `/usr/bin/ld.gold` and `/usr/bin/ld.lld` are intercepted and replaced by `mold`.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a symlink of mold to lld to trick rust into believing it's ld.lld.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ld.mold /usr/bin/ld.lld
```

Then add this in your ~/.cargo/config file to specify ld.lld (which is now mold)

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld",
]
```

Now build without `mold -run` and read the comment (`readelf -p .comment target/debug/program-name`)

```
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (GNU) 11.1.0
  [    13]  mold 0.9.3 (compatible with GNU ld and GNU gold)
```

I'm not really sure how it is that I can set a symlink as ld.lld, I guess I don't have that file currently, but nonetheless this is very hacky and serves to fool any future compiler into using mold, while believing it's using lld (if it's set to use lld). I use this personally because I don't like typing `mold -run` every time, though.

Comment: There is also `-Clinker-flavor=ld` to control how it's invoked, which avoids messing with the file name.